# scilab simple plot instruction returns modulo error

Tags: plot, scilab

`x = [0:0.01:1];  plot(x);`

gives :

> --> plot(x) à la ligne    39 de la fonction modulo ( C:\Program Files\scilab-6.0.2\modules\elementary_functions\macros\modulo.sci
>   ligne 54 ) à la ligne    80 de la fonction plot   (
>   C:\PROGRA~1\SCILAB~1.2\modules\graphics\macros\plot.sci ligne 93 )

Indice invalide.

Can anyone be so kind to tell me why scilab doesn't behave correctly ?

thks in advance

Comment: These statements work perfectly. Please retry with a freshly started Scilab.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have redefined the int function somewhere because line 39 of the modulo function is

```
 i = n - int(n ./ m) .* m
```

If I enter

```
 int=1:3;
 x = [0:0.01:1];  plot(x);
```

I obtain exactly the same error.

In previous Scilab versions function redefinition throw a warning. But sadly it has been removed....

Comment: The function protection system still exists, please see https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.2/en_US/funcprot.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem, but I recommend that you use `pot2d` instead. You will lose compatibility with MATLAB `plot` syntax, though.